# How can I deactivate the gnome desktop of my ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, netbook, home-server, x-windows

I'm running a home server on my old laptop (atom cpu).

I installed ubuntu 12.04 server edition, but I also installed ubuntu-desktop.
So, when I turn it on, ubuntu desktop is shown.

I sometimes use GUI, but I want to turn the ubuntu-desktop (gnome-desktop) off when I don't use it.

I think I can save resources by turning off the GUI.
It's necessary since my laptop's performance is not very good and it often becomes very hot.

I guess I can run ubuntu-desktop on my terminal with "startx" command.
But, I don't know how to turn the X window off for a moment.

Anybody have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

--- Following is written after I chose the answer.

```
$ sudo stop lightdm 
lightdm stop/waiting
```

with this command, I can turn off the x window. But, I can't get tty1 on my laptop.

I put that command from outside with ssh connection.

And, I can turn the x window on outside.

```
X: user not authorized to run the X server, aborting.
xinit: server error
```

But, I can get it back with start lightdm command.

```
$ sudo start lightdm 
lightdm start/running, process 5673
```

I'm not sure this is good or not.

And I don't know I can save my resources when I stop lightdm.

Comment: You can get back to tty1 on the console of the system with Ctrl+Alt+F1. Switch back to the tty7 (where X usually runs) with Ctrl+Alt+F7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To control the X environment, use `sudo service gdm stop` and `sudo service gdm start` once the system has booted up. To make permanent changes, you need to update the runlevel at which ubuntu auto-starts `gdm` (Gnome Desktop Manager), and set it to not start on boot up. You should be able to run these commands from an SSH shell remotely.

Comment: as SystemV was replaced by upstart a while ago, the concept of runlevels is no longer valid on the last few Ubuntu versions (see also [this issue at AskUbuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com/questions/115469/cannot-change-runlevel-from-5-to-3)).

Comment: @Izzy Argh, I feel old now :<

Comment: @Darth_Android: Don't worry. Took me a while to get used to as well. To be honest: It took until a few days ago when I was trying to deactivate some unused services myself that I found out :D

Comment: For me, I want to do it manually. So, I chose this first answer. Thank you all for other answers, too. 
In fact, I should do [sudo stop lightdm](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65856/how-does-one-exit-the-x-server). I can find the way by the keywords from your answers.

Answer (score 7):

I've tried other options with newer version of Ubuntu (Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS) and they didn't work.
What did the trick for me was the following command:

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

Reboot and it will show only the console.

You can revert it running:

```
systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

And reboot again.

Comment: A piece of explanation would make the answer better. What does the command really do? Why did it help? Are there side effects?

Comment: This command modifies systemd configuration. systemd is the program that controls the startup process of newer versions of Ubuntu. Setting the multi-user target rather than the graphical one prevents a graphical boot. This is a good clean way to achieve the result desired by the questioner.

Comment: How do you undo this command once you run it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently not at my Ubuntu machine, but am writing "AFAIR":

check the `/etc/init` directory, where you should find a file named `gdm.conf` (which is used to handle the gdm service). If that's there (i.e. I remember it correctly), just type the following in a shell:

```
sudo echo "manual">/etc/init/gdm.override
sudo service gdm stop
```

Now you've stopped the gdm (Gnome Display Manager) and thus X -- after you told Upstart this service should be handled manually. So it will no longer start automatically; but if you need it, you can simply issue an `sudo service gdm start` to bring it up again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Disable `gdm` at boot:

   ```
   sudo dpkg-divert --rename --add /etc/init/gdm.conf
   ```
2. Authorize users to start `X`:

   ```
   echo "allowed_users=console" | sudo tee -a /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config
   ```
3. Automatically start `X` after login on `tty1`:

   In your `.profile` or `.bash_profile`, add:

   ```
   if [ -z "$DISPLAY" ] && [ $(tty) = /dev/tty1 ]; then 
       startx
   fi
   ```

   Logging in other `tty` will not start `gdm` or `X`.

See also [this question on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/137776/disable-gdm-in-ubuntu-10-04).